# Using curl/libcurl in a C Ruby extension

Tags: c, ruby, curl, libcurl, ruby-c-extension

To preface: I am very new to C, so I am probably missing something obvious but have been running around for days trying to figure out what it is...

I am trying to create a Ruby C extension that will work on both Mac and PC and that uses libcurl to download files.

Basically, all the tool does is gets a list of files from Ruby, downloads the files and puts them where Ruby tells them to.

I have the extension working from within Ruby and have compiled a C extension to interface with Ruby.

Basically my code looks like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/types.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include "ruby.h"

VALUE Test = Qnil;

void Init_test();

VALUE download_file(VALUE self, VALUE from, VALUE to);

void Init_test()
{
    Test = rb_define_class("Test", rb_cObject);
    rb_define_method(Test, "download_file", download_file, 2);
}

VALUE download_file(VALUE self, VALUE from, VALUE to)
{
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;

    char *url = STR2CSTR(from);
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = STR2CSTR(to);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        // curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I am having problems with is getting libcurl to actually work:

```
$ ruby test.rb
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _curl_easy_init
  Referenced from: /path/to/test.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _curl_easy_init
  Referenced from: /path/to/test.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap
```

I am using Ruby's `mkmf` to make a Makefile for my extension:

```
require 'mkmf'
extension_name = 'test'
dir_config(extension_name)
create_makefile(extension_name)
```

I am assuming that when compiling the extension, the Makefile cannot find that Curl files but since I am new to C/Ruby extensions I cannot figure out why that would be.

When I run `curl-config --cflags` this is what I get:

```
$  curl-config --cflags
-I/usr/local/include
```

My libcurl include/library files are:

```
/usr/local/include/curl/
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.dylib
```

My setup:

- Mac OSX 10.6.4
- Ruby 1.8.6-p420
- Curl 7.21.7-DEV (i386-apple-darwin10.7.0) libcurl/7.21.7-DEV OpenSSL/0.9.8l zlib/1.2.3

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Have you had a look at [curb](http://curb.rubyforge.org/) as an example?

Comment: @tadman how does one look at the source? Can't find any links...

Comment: @tadman nevermind! `svn checkout http://curb.rubyforge.org/svn/`

Comment: Why C when there are so many good Ruby libraries that can do this?

Comment: @Mark because the extension is meant to run in Google SketchUp which has an outdated and stripped down version of Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell mkmf to link to libcurl when building your extension. The command to use is [`have_library`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.6/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/Object.html#method-i-have_library).

In your `exconf.rb`, add

```
have_library("curl", "curl_easy_init")
```

before the call to `create_makefile`.

Also, I don't think you need the `dir_config(extension_name)` line.

(On a Mac, you can see what libraries are linked to a binary with `otool -L`. Try

```
otool -L test.bundle
```

before and after adding `have_library`, you should see a line something like `/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.1.0)` added.)

Comment: you're absolutely right. That was what was missing. I did find it out the hard way before you posted your answer but it is nice to know about otool, which is very useful. Is the "curl_easy_init" part necessary? What does it do?

Comment: @Dana I'm not really sure what the second arg is for, it seems to work without it. I think maybe it's so you can check that the library you want actually has a given function.

Comment: Yes I think you're right. `have_library("curl")` works just fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`Symbol not found: _curl_easy_init` sounds like a link error to me.  It seems like you should be passing some flags to your linker (see `curl-config --libs`)

Comment: cam, thanks for your answer! It did end up being a linker issue, but matt's answer was a bit more specific. Thanks for the info though.